# Big Problem since doing a clean install of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: grub2, keyboard

not accepting password so cant get into system. No Icons and Ctrl + T does not open terminal. Completely blocked. Everything at first worked fine. Then keyboard stopped working tried other keyboards plus on screen keyboard but none worked. Tried rebooting to get into recovery mode but the mouse although working ok could not scroll down to recovery so the system started. Please help. Already I hate 20.04 LTS

Comment: Since your install was recent, do you still have your LiveUSB installer? If you boot into the "Try Ubuntu" environment, do your keyboard and mouse work properly again? Have you tried your keyboard/mouse on a different system? Tried a different keyboard/mouse on your system? Changed batteries if wireless?

Comment: Also try the keyboard with all of your USB sockets if USB. If no change, did you try using the keyboard at the GRUB menu? If it works there, select recovery mode with your keyboard (GRUB doesn't use the mouse).

Comment: Several people had the same problem and stated as most likely a kernel confusion involving an update for hot keys They and others had had a similar problem and also offered CLI solutions. No it was not my keyboard as it worked both wirelessly and wired with my old PC

Comment: sorry forgot to say. The keyboard sometimes worked when using a "try Ubuntu" as it runs from ram as opposed to HDD. but in trying to install Ubuntu the keyboard stopped working. Any way I ran a full Ubuntu OS DVD disk. Used ubuntu apps to open a terminal At that stage in the apps I noticed a keyboard icon named Input method. I clicked on it and my keyboard started working and has continued to work. It also showed a notice with defined codes to assist. I did not need to input any coding as my keyboard began to work immediately. sorry if I offended but the information came from help forums